# Zoho Books API search using OR operator

Tags: zoho, zohobooks

We are using Zoho books for our application and we have integrated the Zoho books API with our platform.

For some scenery, we need to search in the list API using the OR operator. But we could not find anything about it in the documentation. 
In the query param, we are sending the following:

```
{
      organization_id: organizationId,
      customer_name_contains: 'pmtpd',
      status: 'draft',
}
```

Here the params are getting applied using AND operator. As a result, we are just getting one data while we have so much data with the status as draft. Our goal for this particular query is to match either with `customer_name_contains` or `status`

How can we do this? We are calling the estimates list API. but we need similar things for other APIs as well.